# Why are some Swift standard library functions not recognized in playground?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, swift-playground

There's a function called `countElements()` which is supposed to be a standard library function in Swift *(The function appears on page 160 in the current Swift 2.0 updated version of 'The Swift Programming Language')*.

So, shouldn't the code below just work?

[image: Playground]

Comment: You have an outdated version of the Swift iBook.  `countElements` became `count` and has been replaced again and in Swift 2.0 is called like this:  `stringA.characters.count`

Comment: By the way, "page 160" has no meaning in an electronic book because the page numbers change with the font size.

Comment: @vacawama you're right on both counts. Just got my update. Thanks

Comment: @eric Is everything working as intended?

Comment: @JAL yes, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Swift 2.0, there is no longer a `countElements(...)` method.  Use `stringA.characters.count` instead.  `characters` returns an array of Characters from the String, and `count` returns the number of items in the Character array.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID297

Comment: 15 seconds faster than me, so +1 to you.  More information found under the ["Measuring Strings has changed again"](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift2) section of this Swift2 blog post.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDautermann, also added a link to the Swift docs.